# Symfony2 mthaml syntax

Tags: javascript, symfony, haml, mthaml

Situation:
I have to place many scripts in "javascripts" native twig block.

```
- javascripts 'assets/js/jquery.js' 'assets/js/some1.coffee' 'assets/js/some2.coffee' ...  'assets/js/someN.coffee' output="assets/js/all.js"
    %script( type="text/javascript" src="#{asset_url~(app.environment == 'dev' ? '?'~random() :'' )}" )
```

How to put scripts each in particular line?

Example:

```
- javascripts 'assets/js/jquery.js' 
'assets/js/some1.coffee' 
'assets/js/some2.coffee' ...  
'assets/js/someN.coffee' 
output="assets/js/all.js"
    %script( type="text/javascript" src="#{asset_url~(app.environment == 'dev' ? '?'~random() :'' )}" )
```

Error:

> An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template
>   ("Illegal nesting: nesting within interpolated string is illegal in
>   ... bla bla bla ... layout.html.haml".

Please don't offer `assets/js/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and easy: Define your asset collections in `config.yml` (or an `assetic.yml` file that you import) instead of in the template:

```
assetic:
    assets:
        # An array of named assets (e.g. some_asset, some_other_asset)
        js_collection_one:
            inputs: 
                - assets/js/some1.coffee
                - assets/js/some2.coffee
                # ...
```

Then in your haml template:

```
 - javascripts '@js_collection_one' output="assets/js/all.js"
     %script( type="text/javascript" src="#{asset_url~(app.environment == 'dev' ? '?'~random() :'' )}" )
```